# Dynamically checkout a repo into a fixed directory

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline that can be triggered by more than one repos:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: A
      type: git
      name: MyProject/A
      trigger:
        - main
    - repository: B
      type: git
      name: MyProject/B
      trigger:
        - main
    - repository: C
      type: git
      name: MyProject/C
      trigger:
        - main
```

At runtime, I know which of the repos triggered the pipeline by looking at the `Build.Repository.Name` variable. What I want to do is to check it out to a fixed directory `s/source_repo`. I tried a few options:

```
# 1: syntax error
- checkout: $(Build.Repository.Name)

# 2: syntax error
- checkout: git://MyProject/$(Build.Repository.Name)

# 3: error: missing password. Input prompt disabled
- bash: git clone $(Build.Repository.Uri) s/source_repo
```

I only need the repo that triggered the build and ignore the other two. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week of being stuck on this, some colleagues suggested that I look into the Personal Access Token of the job, accessible via the `System.AccessToken` variable:

```yaml
steps:
  #  Dynamically checkout a repo
  - bash: |
      git clone -c http.extraheader="Authorization: Bearer $token" $repo $dest
    env:
      token: $(System.AccessToken)
      repo: $(Build.Repository.Uri)
      dest: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/source_repo
    displayName: Checkout $(Build.Repository.Name)
```

Comment: Nice! Glad that you figured that one out. This should work for Azure DevOps repos, but I'm not sure about others, like GitHub/Bitbucket/etc...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, something like this wouldn't work:

```yaml
- checkout: $(Build.Repository.Name)
    path: s/$(Build.Repository.Name)
```

So, the best you can do is this:

```yaml
  # We need to checkout at least one repo to get auth headers.
- checkout: self
  path: s/.self
  # Shave off couple of seconds, we don't need full repo history for this one.
  fetchDepth: 1
  # Allow subsequent git commands on _this_ repo to run authenticated.
  persistCredentials: true

  # Get auth token from _this_ repo and apply it globally.
- bash: git config --global --add http.extraheader "$(git config http."$(git config remote.origin.url)".extraheader)"

  # We don't need this repo anymore
- bash: rm -rf 's/.self'

  # Checkout repo that triggered build. This will work since we've set up auth header earlier.
- bash: git clone '$(Build.Repository.Uri)' 's/source_repo'
```

The code above works for me for Bitbucket Cloud repos.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a more succinct solution and have posted it here for future Googlers.